# Error when calling base member function from within a lambda

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm attempting to call the base class implementation of a member function inside a lambda.

Is the following code that **clang++** accepts and **gcc** rejects well formed by the standard?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
protected:
    void fn() { }
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
public:
    void fn()
    {
        [&]() {
            Base::fn(); /// compilation error here
        }();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.fn();
}
```

**Error message:**

```
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:6:10: error: void Base::fn() is protected
     void fn() { }
          ^
test.cpp:16:22: error: within this context
             Base::fn();
                      ^
```

**Compiler versions:**

> gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8)

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.3-5ubuntu4 (branches/release_33) (based on LLVM 3.3)
```

Comment: well of course gcc rejects it, it's a c compiler

Comment: @aaronman: [that is incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377397/why-gcc-can-compile-c-code-but-can-not-link).

Comment: @JesseGood gcc is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58972). A lambda is like defining a local class and has the same access rights.